# VIM + VDebug in WSL2 while having WAMP and XDebug on Windows

Tags: debugging, wsl

Whenever I need to write something I use VIM. However most of my work requires that I use Windows OS.
I have WAMP server running and I used to edit PHP files just in VIM in WSL2. I then thought why not to set up a debugger and take advantage of it in VIM.

I managed to set everything up (surprisingly, VIM listens to port 9000 in WSL2 and establishes communication with XDebug from native Windows WAMP installation). However, when I hit a breakpoint VIM (VDebug to be exact) tries to open file and here comes a problem:

XDebug passes file path as `D:\something\htdocs\somefile.php` but in WSL this file has path
`/mnt/d/something/htdocs/somefile.php`

As a result I have an empty tab in VIM.

Does anyone know a workaround for that? I almost got it working (staying in linux terminal and using VIM would be a dream)...

P.S.
The obvious workaround is to set up XAMP in WSL but this is too messy. I already have tuned WAMP setup and want to stick to it.

**Edit 1:**

Using `path_maps` option in VDebug I managed

```
let g:vdebug_options = { 'path_maps': { 'D:': '/mnt/d' } }
```

to get almost the correct paths. The problem is that windows paths use `\` and WSL recognizes `\` as escape character. So I need to convert `\` to `/`, but that seems to be outside the scope of VDebug `path_maps` option. Investigating...

Comment: If you can hook into the part where vim gets a file from `XDebug`, it should be straightforward to make the substitution (something like `tr(xdebug_path, '\', '/')->substitute('^\(\u\):\(.*\)', '/mnt/\l\1\2', '')` worked on your example for me)

Comment: I don't know anything XDebug but if you can find some way to filter or pre-process paths then you could use `wslpath` which translates between WSL and Win paths, either direction. (It is almost identical to Cygwin's `cygpath`, if you're familiar with that. Same flags and everything.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was `path_maps` option in `vdebug` plugin:

```
let g:vdebug_options = { 'path_maps': { 'D:\Dropbox': '/mnt/d/Dropbox' } }
```

The code of how path_maps are parsed is located in `util.py` file of the plugin and reads (at the time of writing this post):

```
  219         if opts.Options.isset('path_maps'):
    1             sorted_path_maps = sorted(
    2                 opts.Options.get('path_maps', dict).items(),
    3                 key=lambda l: len(l[0]), reverse=True)
    4             for remote, local in sorted_path_maps:
    5                 if remote in ret:
    6                     log.Log("Replacing remote path (%s) with local path (%s)"
    7                             % (remote, local), log.Logger.DEBUG)
    8                     if not local.endswith('/') and remote.endswith('/'):
    9                         local = local+'/'
   10                     elif local.endswith('/') and not remote.endswith('/'):
   11                         local = local[:-1]
   12                     ret = ret.replace(remote, local, 1)
   13
   14                     # determine remote path separator and replace by local
   15                     local_sep = self._findSeparator(local)
   16                     remote_sep = self._findSeparator(remote)
   17                     if local_sep and remote_sep and remote_sep != local_sep:
   18                         ret = ret.replace(remote_sep, local_sep)
   19                     break
   20
   21         return ret
```

As you can see it tries to determine the local and remote separator.

The only caveat is that `'D:\' : '/mnt/d/'` won't work since it removes the trailing separator in remote path, so "D:\Dropbox" will become "/mnt/dDropbox/".

I therefore had to add one folder deep into the path explicitly.

Thank you everyone who commented - these comments led to the correct solution.

P.S.
One could modify the substitution in `util.py` as suggested, but I decided to use more robust solution, even though it won't work for files in "D:" root folder (don't need that anyway).

Comment: That's a pretty brittle routine they have there. I wouldn't be able to resist extending it so local can be a "filter" script/executable which takes a remote-type path as it's only param. Specify `{ 'filter': 'filterprog' }` (or whatever notation would be safe). Then with `{ 'filter': 'wslpath' }` and `ret` value `D:\foo\bar`, `wslpath 'D:\foo\bar'` would be run and you'd get `'/mnt/d/foo/bar'`...and it would work for any value of `ret`. But I've been known to get carried away. ;)

Comment: And this could be used by Cygwin users, too, with "filter" `cygpath`. :) (I'm a heavy user of both WSL and Cyg.)